# we have array of 3 digit numbers sort only the middle digit of the array of numbers for eg:i/p =540,984,902 and the o/p is 500,944,982

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, numbers

we have an array of 3 digit numbers sort only the middle digit of the arrayof numbers
I/p=540,984,902
O/p=500,944,982 and the middle number is change by using one array

I tried only the swap options .i am excepting by using one array

Comment: what exactly is your question? what have you tried? where is your code failing?
the middle number isn't changed by using one array, it's changed by the code you wrote, but since you don't show that code, we won't likely figure out what happened. Either way, the sorting of the middle numbers seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{540, 984, 902};// or however many 3-digit numbers

int[] mids = new int[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  mids[i] = (numbers[i] / 10) % 10;
}

Arrays.sort(mids);

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i] = (numbers[i] / 100) * 100 + mids[i] * 10 + numbers[i] % 10;
  System.out.println("a[" + i + "] " + numbers[i]);
}
```